# How to debug MVC3/WebAPI routing 404 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

My WebAPI route is defined as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "BuildModels",
  routeTemplate: "api/build/models/{productLine}/{language}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Build", action = "GetModels" }
);
```

Controller:

```
public class BuildController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetModels(string productLine, string language)
    {
        // Omitted for brevity, I don't feel it's pertinent
        // but if you disagree I will fill this in.  
        // Nothing has changed in here and it worked before.
        return await ...;
    }
}
```

**/api/build/models/x/en**

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/api/build/models/x/en&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**/api/build/models/x/**

```
{"Message":"The arguments value is not valid : {language}"}
```

---

All of my routes are working except the ones on this single controller, which were working before. I obviously changed something, just can't figure out what.

Comment: Try Web Api Route debugger http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx.

Comment: It could also be related to your dependency injector, if you are using one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried activating custom errors?

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/customerrors/500.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/customerrors/404.html" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="/customerrors/403.html" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: No, this is an AJAX request so I don't want to redirect.  Furthermore, I'm using NLog, the HttpException I included was caught by it and the HTML for the [YSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_of_death) is returned.